# Remote server return an error: (500) Internal server error

Tags: c#, .net, rest, jira

I'm trying to get issues from JIRA cloud like below:

```
 public List<Issue> GetIssues(
        string jql,
        List<string> fields = null,
        int startAt = 0,
        int maxResult = 50)
    {
        fields = fields ?? new List<string> { "summary", "status", "assignee" };

        SearchRequest request = new SearchRequest();
        request.Fields = fields;
        request.JQL = jql;
        request.MaxResults = maxResult;
        request.StartAt = startAt;

        string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);
```

this gives "data" as below:

{"jql":"project = CI","startAt":0,"maxResults":50,"fields":["summary","status","assignee"]}

Then, I'm calling run query like below:

```
string result = runQuery(JiraResource.search, data, "POST");
```

//run query defination:

```
 public string runQuery(
        JiraResource resource,
        string argument = null,
        string data = null,
        string method = "GET")
    {
        string url = string.Format("{0}{1}",str_baseURL,resource.ToString()); //This is my URL : https://clientname.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/search

       // string url = string.Format("{0}{1}/", str_baseURL);
        if(argument != null) // as my argument is not null here , so my url is now below
        {

            url = string.Format("{0}{1}/",url,argument); //https://clientname.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/search{"jql":"project =               CI","startAt":0,"maxResults":50,"fields":["summary","status","assignee"]}/
        }
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = method;
        /*if (data != null) //for time being commented it, becoz of error
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                writer.Write(data);
            }
        }*/
        string base64Credentials = GetEncodedCredentials();
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Credentials);
        HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse; //Here Im getting "Remote server returned an error(500) Internal server error"
        string result = string.Empty;
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        { result = reader.ReadToEnd(); }

        return result;
    }
```

What I'm doing wrong? Please note that, my other method like "GetProjects" is working fine and I'm getting JSON. Please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved: I made it like this:

```
 string url = string.Format("{0}{1}", str_baseURL, resource.ToString());
        if (argument != null)
        {
            method = "POST";
            //url = string.Format("{0}{1}/", url, argument); 
        }
        else
        {
            method = "GET";
        }
        data = argument;
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = method;
```

It was the issue with "when to use POST and when GET".

Answer (score 0):

If you're making a request to a server hosted by Atlassian (as it appears you are), then a 500 Internal Server Error response indicates a problem at Atlassian's end, not yours.  I would recommend contacting Atlassian for support.

Comment: I have one method like this and this is working fine: public List<ProjectDescription> GetProjects()
        {
            List<ProjectDescription> projects = new List<ProjectDescription>();
            string strAutho = runQuery(JiraResource.project);
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ProjectDescription>>(strAutho);
            
        }

Comment: @TryingBest: whether you have another method that works fine may be relevant to Atlassian support, but not here.  The 500 error is a problem at Atlassian's end, and nobody on StackOverflow will be able to help fix this problem unless they happen to work for Atlassian.  What are you doing wrong in your code?  Quite possibly nothing.  As I said before, contact Atlassian support to sort this out.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have posted to them. Hope to get an answer soon.